# Variable Declaration Inside For Loop Initialization Statement

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, coding-style, variable-declaration

I have a simple question with regards to initializing for loops.

Here is my for loop declaration:

```
for (int i=player.x-xIndex-1; i<=player.x+xIndex+1; i++)
{
    for (int j=player.y-yIndex-1; j<=player.y+yIndex+1; j++)
    {

    }
}
```

My question is:

Is it bad practice to have the values of the indices i and j be set to non-static integer values at declaration?

Will the code just evaluate the minimum and maximum values of i and j *once* at beginning of execution, or will it evaluate those values (i.e. player.x+xIndex+1, etc.) *every* single time the loop executes.

Any light you guys can shed on my problem would be awesome!

I'm a freakin' amateur, guys. Seriously.

Thanks :D

Comment: FYI - this is actually a basic C question since none of the code in the question is specific to Objective-C (which is a superset of C).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an amateur question at all. The "initialization" expressions are calculated only on the first run through, because of course they're only used that one time.

For the loop's "condition" (the middle expression that is tested at the end of every iteration), in the worst case it can be evaluated every iteration. Because what if (in this case) `player.y` actually changes during the loop?

However, most modern compilers will likely not compute that whole thing every loop if they can detect that the end value is provably never changing during the loop.

If you wanted to be double sure and manhandle the path of execution, you can explicitly "hoist" the conditional end expression out of the loop yourself, like:

```
int maxValue = foo.x + y.bar + 12 + myString.length;
for (int i = 0; i < maxValue; i++) {
    ....
```

But now the standard style disclaimer: optimizing prematurely can make your code less readable for no provable gains. Unless you're doing real work in that condition expression, or the loop is running bazillions of iterations, some additional computation won't hurt you much, and might be worth keeping so that it's clearer to yourself and others what you're trying to do.

Comment: My loop only runs 221 times, I suppose that would count as "not running bazillions of iterations"?

Comment: Also, that's a very important point to make with your 'standard style disclaimer', and much appreciated, it's something I don't bear in mind nearly enough.

Comment: @J-Rock: Re iterations, correct. (As with anything, you'd have to take into consideration your specific platform, what work you're doing in the loop conditional, and how sensitive this code path is to performance. But a couple hundred iterations on modern machines is nothing.) Stick around and you'll hear that readability disclaimer often-- it's conventional wisdom (though not always obvious when you're getting started) that premature optimization (as it's called) can hurt your code overall more than it helps if you do it blindly-- maximizing runtime speed will not always be the priority.

Comment: @J-Rock: Also worth mentioning-- definitely avoid having any code in your conditional expression that has *side-effects* (ie, that changes the state of something). That could easily have unintended consequences even if it was performant to execute.